# Yodlee ASP.NET C# Integration

Tags: yodlee

I have read a thread regarding Yodlee implementation and on one of the responses a user said "It is easy to intergrate your app with Yodlee API" How exactly is it easy to implement Yodlee and integrate it with an existing C# Web App? I don't mind getting dirty, but I would like to know how hard can it get and is there forums out there and enough developer support? Please assist urgently as we need to test and implement Yodlee before the end of the month also note I am new to Yodlee and API integration.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to get dirty at all. It is so simple to implement Yodlee in any .net language. Yodlee provide a client library for .net as well, all you need to do is to wrap your business logic around the library. On other hand if you wish to take greater control of api calling as well, you will be provided wsdl proxies to the web services, code what ever way you feel good with it.

Comment: @Thabo how did you get on, I am also just starting out with Yodlee and I would be interested to know did you use SOAP or REST and did you get it to work?

Comment: I may be little late to answer for you but I am answering this as I did not see a reply from Thabo. I did implement the same using SOAP for most of the functions and REST is used for transaction download as the result payload is lightweight. Yodlee do suggest to use the combination of soap and rest for the optimized experience.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we did not want SOAP at all, we are striving for purely RESTful in all our operations

Comment: Yodlee do has full support for REST API's, it solely depends on the requirement and the application architecture what decision should be made. I hope by this time you've already implemented your solution for the same. However if you are still looking for some pieces of puzzle to be solved, I would be happy to be your assistance.